# JSON menu, adding sub-level inside the parent LI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have made this JSON menu but struggling getting the sub menu UL inside its parent LI - does anyone have any ideas what I need to adjust here?

JS:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// lets do some JSON magic and make a menu!
JSON = {
   "menu":[
      {
         "id":"contact",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"Contact Us",
         "link":"",
         "content":"contactUs.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      },
      {
         "id":"rules",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Sports Betting Rules",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"types",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Wager Types",
               "link":"",
               "content":"wagerTypes.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content wager-types",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"odds",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Odds & Lines",
               "link":"",
               "content":"oddsAndLines.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"policies",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Rules & Policies",
               "link":"",
               "content":"rulesAndPolicies.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content rules-policies",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"bonuses",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Sports Bonuses",
               "link":"",
               "content":"sportsBonuses.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"conditions",
         "leaf":false,
         "description":"Terms & Conditions",
         "link":"",
         "content":"",
         "cssClass":"",
         "menu":[
            {
               "id":"termsOfService",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Terms of Service",
               "link":"",
               "content":"termsOfService.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            },
            {
               "id":"privacy",
               "leaf":true,
               "description":"Privacy Policy",
               "link":"",
               "content":"privacy.html",
               "cssClass":"static-content",
               "menu":null
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"view",
         "leaf":true,
         "description":"View in: Mobile | Full Site",
         "link":"",
         "content":"view.html",
         "cssClass":"static-content",
         "menu":null
      }
   ]
}

$(document).ready(function () {

    function buildMenu(ul, menu) {
        for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
            var li = $(ul).append('<li id="'+menu[i].id+'" class="'+menu[i].leaf+' '+menu[i].cssClass+'"><a href="'+menu[i].link+'">'+menu[i].content+'</a></li>');
            if (menu[i].menu!=null) {
                var subul=$('<ul id="submenu-'+menu[i].id+'"></ul>');
                $(li).append(subul);
                buildMenu($(subul), menu[i].menu);
            }
        }
    }

    var menu = $(".main-menu");
    buildMenu(menu, JSON.menu);

});

</script>

<div class="main-menu"></div>
```

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in the following point of your code:

```
var li = $(ul).append('<li id="'+menu[i].id+'" class="'+menu[i].leaf+' '+menu[i].cssClass+'"><a href="'+menu[i].link+'">'+menu[i].content+'</a></li>');
```

The method  `append` returns `<ul>` and not `<li>` as you think. So the code does not work as you suppose for this reason. To solve the problem, split the line of code in two:

```
        var li = $('<li id="'+menu[i].id+'" class="'+menu[i].leaf+' '+menu[i].cssClass+'"><a href="'+menu[i].link+'">'+menu[i].content+'</a></li>');
        $(ul).append(li);
```

The complete code here:

```js
var JSON = {
  "menu": [{
    "id": "contact",
    "leaf": true,
    "description": "Contact Us",
    "link": "",
    "content": "contactUs.html",
    "cssClass": "static-content",
    "menu": null
  }, {
    "id": "rules",
    "leaf": false,
    "description": "Sports Betting Rules",
    "link": "",
    "content": "",
    "cssClass": "",
    "menu": [{
      "id": "types",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Wager Types",
      "link": "",
      "content": "wagerTypes.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content wager-types",
      "menu": null
    }, {
      "id": "odds",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Odds & Lines",
      "link": "",
      "content": "oddsAndLines.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content",
      "menu": null
    }, {
      "id": "policies",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Rules & Policies",
      "link": "",
      "content": "rulesAndPolicies.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content rules-policies",
      "menu": null
    }, {
      "id": "bonuses",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Sports Bonuses",
      "link": "",
      "content": "sportsBonuses.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content",
      "menu": null
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "conditions",
    "leaf": false,
    "description": "Terms & Conditions",
    "link": "",
    "content": "",
    "cssClass": "",
    "menu": [{
      "id": "termsOfService",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Terms of Service",
      "link": "",
      "content": "termsOfService.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content",
      "menu": null
    }, {
      "id": "privacy",
      "leaf": true,
      "description": "Privacy Policy",
      "link": "",
      "content": "privacy.html",
      "cssClass": "static-content",
      "menu": null
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "view",
    "leaf": true,
    "description": "View in: Mobile | Full Site",
    "link": "",
    "content": "view.html",
    "cssClass": "static-content",
    "menu": null
  }]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

  function buildMenu(ul, menu) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
      var li = $('<li id="' + menu[i].id + '" class="' + menu[i].leaf + ' ' + menu[i].cssClass + '"><a href="' + menu[i].link + '">' + menu[i].content + '</a></li>');
      $(ul).append(li);
      if (menu[i].menu != null) {
        var subul = $('<ul id="submenu-' + menu[i].id + '"></ul>');
        $(li).append(subul);
        buildMenu($(subul), menu[i].menu);
      }
    }
  }

  var menu = $(".main-menu");
  buildMenu(menu, JSON.menu);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu"></ul>
```

**Note:** I used `<ul class="main-menu"></ul>` instead of your `<div class="main-menu"></div>` because is more correct.

Comment: Thanks mate :) fixed! dont know how i missed that been a long day!

Comment: Just a quick one, if it was menu.json file how could i do it so i load in from that file rather than having the json inside the html file? is that possible?

Comment: You need to publish the JSON file some where and use an AJAX call to load it. In the success callback you can use the loaded JSON and build your menu.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function buildMenu(element, menu) {
    $.each(menu,function(key, obj) {
        var li = element.append('<li id="'+obj.id+'" class="'+obj.leaf+' '+obj.cssClass+'"><a href="'+obj.link+'">'+obj.content+'</a></li>');
        if (obj.menu!=null) {
                var subul=$('<ul id="submenu-'+obj.id+'"></ul>');
                $(li).append(subul);
                buildMenu($(subul), obj.menu);
            }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var menu = $(".main-menu");
    buildMenu(menu, JSON.menu);
});
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
</ul>
```